# Two raspberry pi on one router - SSL

Tags: router, ssl, domain

I have the following:

A router with external ip address 209.xx.xx.xx. This router forwards to the ip address of the first rpi (rpi#1) (ports 80 and 443 to 192.168.1.170) and a random port (1234) to the second pi (rpi#2).

A domain name from noip.com forwards to rpi#1 via 209.xx.xx.xx. I added SSL (letsencrypt) to rpi#1. This is now secure (http -> https).

I have a second rpi (rpi#2) on 192.168.1.139 on the same router. The router forwards a port (1234) to rpi#2. This is not secure (http).

This is all working fine.

Now: I would like to add SSL to rpi#2. However, since noip.com can only forward to one external ip address, I can then not add SSL to rpi#2.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve. You have just one domain (from noip), right? Then why not just copy the same certificate on the second rpi?

Comment: Yes, at the moment i have only one domain. But I need a second domain to map to the second rpi. Maybe, you are on to something with 'copy the same certificate to the second rpi' ....

Comment: One option could be request for the certificate on rpi 1 (noip.com) with an alias in the same certificate (secondnoip.com). This way, you could just copy the certificate in the second rpi and use the same cert on both of them.

Comment: I think you're missing a key concept. A domain name (especially in HTTP/HTTPS context) names an IP address. Your domain name points to 209.xx.xx.xx. It does **not** point to your first Raspberry Pi; it points to your router.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Configure one of the Rpis (or some other always-online device) as an HTTP **reverse proxy**. (You could use a standard webserver such as Nginx or Apache httpd; just create VirtualHosts for both domains and enable proxying.)

Note that since clients only speak to the proxy (and not to the final server), all TLS certificates must be configured on the proxy system. The proxy→final server connection can use plain HTTP, or HTTPS with a custom-made cert, it doesn't matter much.

1. Configure device A to proxy plain HTTP for domain B to device B – *except* for the `/.well-known/acme-challenge` path, which should still be served from device A's /var/www or such.
2. Configure your Let's Encrypt client on device A to obtain certificates for both domains.
3. Configure the proxy on device A to use the new HTTPS certificates.

---

Option 2: Configure one of the Rpis (or some other always-online device) as a **TLS SNI proxy**. The [sniproxy](https://github.com/dlundquist/sniproxy) program can be used for this; it's possible that HAproxy might have a similar option as well.

In this method, TLS will be terminated at the individual servers – the proxy will not need to decrypt the actual data. So each server will need to obtain its own certificates from Let's Encrypt.

However, this *only* works with TLSv1.2 plaintext SNI – it cannot easily work with TLSv1.3 encrypted SNI.

Comment: I have apache installed. Could you explain further option 1? Sorry, still learning!

Comment: Basically add a completely regular vhost for the 2nd domain, just with an additional `ProxyPass` option. Look up [`proxy_module`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [reverse proxy guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html). There are also examples on this site.